# Quadratic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

Here's the question below -

$x^2 - 6x + (p^2 - 6 )^2$ is a perfect square , write down the possible values of p .

My thoughts :

I thought of this expansion method -

$(A-B)^2 = A^2 - 2 AB + B^2$

But I'm not sure how to start ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

There is no need to complicate matters as the path you have indicated. See if the following looks simple and intuitive enough

The only way to complete the square for $x^2 - 6x$ is by adding $9$ to it. So $(p^2 - 6)^2 = 9$. Can you now find the values of $p$ from here ?

Comment: Is there any way to calculate to find the '9' ?

Comment: Yes. The last term = square of the middle term divided by 4 times the first term. In this case,  $LT = 6^2/4 = \color{blue}{9}$. Hope this helps.

Comment: Alright . I got it now . Thank you so much !

Answer (score 2):

You are right. $A=x$ $B=3$ and so, $(P^2-6)^2=9$ which means $P^2-6=+/- 3$ and so, $P^2=9$ or $3$

$P=3$ , $-3$ , $\sqrt{3}$ , $-\sqrt{3}$